# Find directories that don't have a file with specified name

Tags: linux, command-line, find

I've done a good amount of research on this and put together this command, but it appears to be finding the directories that HAVE `scanned.txt` not the directories that don't have `scanned.txt`.

How can I Modify this to fit my needs?

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 2 -not -name 'scanned.txt' -exec dirname {} \; | sort -u >> NOT_SCANNED.txt
```

Thanks

Comment: Not exactly what you asked for: but if you are then going to remove them. Then (on any Unix, **don't try on MS-Windows**) try to remove with `rmdir`. Only empty directories will be removed.

Comment: I dont wait to remove any dirs i just need to find `scanned.txt` in any dir starting from `.` and output any dir that doesnt have `scanned.txt`

Comment: Oh. I grok you now. I though that you were asking about directories that don't have a file in them (i.e. empty) . You may want to edit the question to make it clearer. e.g. "directories that don't have a file with specified name"

Comment: You're selecting files that satisfy the condition `-not -name 'scanned.txt'`, i.e. the files that are not called `scanned.txt`. Since you print the names of the directories containing these files, this is equivalent to printing the names of the directories that contain a file other than `scanned.txt`. (If a directory contains multiple files other than `scanned.txt`, your `find` command prints one line for each file, but `sort -u` removes the duplicates.) Enumerating the directories is not only easier, but even necessary if you want to include empty directories in the output.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, AFAIK, plain `rmdir` shouldn't delete a non-empty directory on Windows either. The [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/rmdir) say: "You can't delete a directory that contains files, including hidden or system files. ", but there's the `/s` switch to recursively delete a whole directory tree.